# How to repeat string n times?

Tags: php, string

Let's say I have `$var="z"` and how to concatenate the z $i times, for example if `$i==5` then $var should be `"zzzzz"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/str_repeat):

```
$repeated = str_repeat($var, $i);
```

With this `$var` is repeated `$i` times.

Answer (score 5):

You use [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/str_repeat). In your case:

```
str_repeat($var, $i);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo $x = str_repeat("x", 5); // "xxxxx" // Hope it helps, one row ;)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
str_repeat(String, Multiplier);
```

EDIT: Wow am I slow ...

Answer (score 1):

try str_repeat
(this should be upvoted once to maintain the sequence)